# Is there a way to know what the returned object is?

Tags: c#, object, return, layer

I have a Helper Class, that i use to pass between the layers on my program. One of the features of this class, is that it returns if the bottom layer has had an error. Also it passes back through the layers the data associated with the routine (ie, returns a database table, string, integer etc..). Currently i add the data via a object type. and the callee routine needs to know what datatype is coming back.
My question is, is there a way to return the object, and also what type of data it is ? and how would i store the type descriptor?

currently this is how is it implemented:

This is an example of the lower level (for a db routine that didn't have a error):

```
      return new MyHelper()
            .AndAddObjectToReturn(rep)
            .AndHasNoErrors();
```

and this bubbles up to the callee code which does this:

```
        .....
        if (contactidHelped.HaveNoErrors())
        {
            repContact contact = (repContact) contactidHelped.GetAttachedDataObject();
            ....
         }
```

what i want to do is on the callee routine, is for it to be ignorant if the datatype and do code like this:

```
        .....
        if (contactidHelped.HaveNoErrors())
        {
            repContact contact = contactidHelped.GetAttachedDataObject();
            ....
         }
```

so that the expected object is what it needs.

Comment: What about this? `var contact = contactidHelped.GetAttachedDataObject();`

Comment: hi.. that will work with strings and ints, but i am mostly mapping back to typed properties in classes. for example: newgroup.ProductTypeOfGroupItemLink  = .... and that is defined by:         public repProductTypes ProductTypeOfGroupItemLink { get; set; }   .. etc..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, you are not able to do it in a simple way. what I can think of to achieve  a similar behavior is to use type constraint at your helper class.

Create a base Helper class (let's say MyHelper) which has a virtual GetAttachedDataObject returning object type, while deriving another class - `MyHelper<T>`, which has a method `GetAttachedData<T>` returning value of type T.

When you initialize/instantiate the helper, instantiate a strong typed `MyHelper<T>`. At the caller, you can cast your MyHelper to your desired `MyHelper<T>` upfront and call GetAttachedData instead of GetAttachedDataObject. of course, you could further tweak this to meet your needs.

but this is not ideal either - it still requires you to do casting at some point, though I believe it could reduce the needs of casting.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `GetAttachedDataObject()` around by simply storing it as an object, for example

```
var attachedDataObject = contactidHelped.GetAttachedDataObject();
```

Then when you need to access a specific property or method for any given object just check the type like:

```
if (attachedDataObject is repContact) {
    // your code here
}
```

However, I would suggest you check how [Interfaces](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18743/Interfaces-in-C-For-Beginners) work, maybe it will be more suited to your needs.